# Java Spring 4 Nested object InvalidPropertyException

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

I have a problem with nested object: Every time crash with the excepion

1. On my List with *Number format exception*
2. On my object with
   *org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException*

Can you help me where is the error? Why the post body isn't interpreted correctly?

Here is the AngularJS

```
var form = { text1: $scope.text1,
                 text2: $scope.text2};

var d ={    one: "textone",
            two: "texttwo",
       myObject: form,
   myListString: ["one", "two"] };

var toPost =   $.param(d);
$http({
         method:'post',
            url:'http://localhost:8080/TestSpringPrj/test',
           data:toPost,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
       dataType:"json"
               })
```

My Java Class:

```
public class MyClassTest{
    private String one;
    private String two;
    private MyObjForm myObject;
    private List<String>  myListStrin

    public MyClassTest() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    ///////GETTERS & SETTERS
}
```

My Controller

```
@Controller
public class RicercaAvanzataT {
    @RequestMapping(value="/test")
    public ModelAndView processSubmit(@ModelAttribute MyClassTesttest) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("response");
        System.out.println("Test was fine");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you are using `@ModelAttribute` whereas you should have used `@RequestBody`.

Comment: done but now i receive 415 Error (Unsupported Media Type)

Comment: Your js say that is form encoded but you are posting JSON. SO what is it  you want. Do you want to do a regular form submit (through AJAX) or do you want to send JSON to the server...

Comment: Right, i'm trying to send JSON to server i have converted x-www-form-urlencoded in application/json and on mu @Controller i have added @RequestMapping(value="/ricercaAvanzataTre", produces = "application/json")

SO: 403 Forbidden, i'm getting crazy.

Comment: You don't need the produces part. Also 403 means you have no access.

Comment: Thanks, but i continue to receive 415

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use @RequestBody, where it passes the whole body of your json request to converters and then to controller methods. Whereas @ModelAttribute just fill the model from HttpServletRequest

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test")
    public ModelAndView processSubmit(@RequestBody MyClassTesttest) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("response");
        System.out.println("Test was fine");
        return mv;
    }
```

Comment: Done but now i receive 415 (Unsupported Media Type)